# ES6: Can't Deconstruct inside a call constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, object-literal, es6-class

I'm trying to use ES6 Deconstructing inside a class constructor but get an unknown token error.  Here's an example:

// imports/server/a-and-b.js

```
class A {
  constructor(id) {
    // make MongoDB call and store inside this variable
    let {
      firstName: this._FirstName // => Throws here
    } = CollectionName.findOne({userId: id});
  }
}

export class B extends A {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }
  get FirstName() {
    return this._FirstName;
  }
}
```

// imports/server/test.js

```
import { B } from 'imports/server/a-and-b.js'

const b = new B('123')

const FirstName = b.FirstName;
```

The same deconstruction will work outside the class:

// another-test.js

```
// make MongoDB call and store inside this variable
let {
  firstName: FirstName // works fine
} = CollectionName.findOne({userId: id});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this can be done like so:

```
constructor(id) {
  // make MongoDB call and store inside this variable
  ({ firstName: this._FirstName } = CollectionName.findOne({userId: id}));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is incorrect. What you are trying to do is not possible. Assuming the findOne method is synchronous you need to do this:

```
constructor(id) {
    // make MongoDB call and store inside this variable
    let { firstName } = CollectionName.findOne({userId: id});
    this._FirstName = firstName;
  }
```

Comment: it would be similar to trying to do this `let this._Firstname = ...` - invalid syntax